# How to look for the csv file that i have written in my heroku app

Tags: heroku, filesystems

I am very new to heroku. I have created an app using python in Heroku. In my app, I am generating a report at the end of every operation/transaction. I would like to know how and where can i see the report. The report is written in .csv format. I am staging my code through github.

Will there be any file-systems within the Heroku where i can check for the report generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has an "ephemeral" file system that resets itself whenever a dyno restarts.

Any files that were procedurally written to the file system should be able to be retrieved as long as the same process that writes them is also the process that attempts to retrieve them--but as soon as the dyno restarts, those files will be removed.

For more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem